# Accessing a JavaScript variable from Chrome Remote Debugging Protocol

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, remote-debugging

I am connected to Chrome (34.0.1847.132) via the [Remote Debugging Protocol](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/protocol/tot/runtime), and I have successfully enabled runtime and console debugging. I can send Chrome messages and will get the responses back.

Now, I'd like to inspect the properties of a certain JavaScript variable in the current page. So, in my HTML page, I have the following statement in a script tag:

```
window.foo = {
  'bar' : 'baz'
}
```

I can query the property with `window.foo.bar` from the console in Chrome itself, but I cannot do it via remote debugging, since I receive an error.

To get the property, I send this JSON message to the WebSocket:

```
{
  :method => "Runtime.getProperties", 
  :params => {
    :objectId => "window.foo.bar"
  }, 
  "id"=>2
}
```

And I get the response:

```
{
    "error" => {
           "code" => -32000,
        "message" => "Inspected frame has gone"
    },
       "id" => 2
}
```

Similarly, if I try to `Runtime.evaluate` the expression `window.foo.bar`, I get:

```
{
    "result" => {
           "result" => {
                   "type" => "object",
               "objectId" => "{\"injectedScriptId\":1,\"id\":1}",
              "className" => "TypeError",
            "description" => "TypeError: Cannot read property 'bar' of undefined"
        },
        "wasThrown" => true
    },
        "id" => 2
}
```

What would cause the "inspected frame" to be gone? What is that, even?
Or is the `objectId` something completely different?

How do I access the property of a JavaScript variable then?

Comment: Can you specify keep alive interval?

Comment: It's not a problem of the web socket connection being dropped. It stays open all the time. In fact, I can send commands back and forth without issues, just the ` Runtime.getProperties` makes the inspected frame "gone".

Answer (score 2):

`Runtime.evaluate` and `Runtime.callFunctionOn` return a `RemoteObject` that has objectId field, in case the expression has evaluated into an Object. Further object identifiers will be returned for the object's properties if you enumerate them via `Runtime.getProperties`.

Answer (score 1):

What's important to know is that `Runtime.evaluate` [accesses at the level of `window`](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/google-chrome-developer-tools/getproperties/google-chrome-developer-tools/CKeuDq9fDuk/vYLzfrH2RKsJ), so if you want to access `window.document`, you need `document` as an expression.

Doing this worked, in the end:

```
window.document.foo = "bar"
```

And in the request:

```
{
  :method => "Runtime.evaluate", 
  :params => {
    :expression => "document.foo"
  },
  "id" => 1
}
```

You may want to set `returnByValue` in the parameters to `true` if you want to access object properties and such.

Comment: But `window.window === window`?

Comment: Yes, I know. But if I set `window.foo`, I cannot query `foo`, and `window.foo` neither. Don't ask me why this is.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [source](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/blink.git/+/b3c994de3c63f0015226df0d089eef929979dd5d/Source/WebCore/inspector/InspectorRuntimeAgent.cpp) search for `"Inspected frame has gone"` it might give you some insight on what is happening.
This does look like a good candidate.

```
void InspectorRuntimeAgent::getProperties(ErrorString* errorString, const String& objectId, const bool* const ownProperties, RefPtr<InspectorArray>* result)
{
    InjectedScript injectedScript = m_injectedScriptManager->injectedScriptForObjectId(objectId);
    if (injectedScript.hasNoValue()) {
        *errorString = "Inspected frame has gone";
    return;
    }
    injectedScript.getProperties(errorString, objectId, ownProperties ? *ownProperties : false, result);
}
```

You are passing `window.foo.bar` as const String& objectId.
I would assume it cannot find it, as you must be hitting `injectedScript.hasNoValue()`.

Comment: Thanks, but this is more of a comment than an answer, really. It just raises more questions.. it seems like it's looking for some injected script? What would that be?

Comment: You are passing window.foo.bar as const String& objectId? I would assume it cannot find it. Try "foo.bar" instead

Comment: `window.foo.bar`, like mentioned in the question. But perhaps it should be something completely different -- I don't know, I cannot tell from the documentation.

Comment: I have edited my previous comment cause it was stupid, sorry about that. Please try foo.bar without window.

Comment: No dice, same error message. (The connection is kept alive though, afterwards.)

Comment: How about window.foo without bar or just foo? your hitting injectedScript.hasNoValue() I would assume input is incorrect.

Comment: Can it be that this is intended for html element id attribute and not javascript object?

Comment: No, because that's what [DOM debugging](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/protocol/tot/dom) is for. Runtime debugging is for JavaScript. I appreciate your persistence in trying to help, but I think we're on the same level of knowledge here.